# ¿Se necesita un dispositivo Apple, para poder solamente hacer el diseño de una App para iOS en Xamarin con Visual Studio?

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, xamarin

Necesito hacer una App para iOS con Xamarin en Visual Studio 2015, pero el dispositivo que me darán, llega la próxima semana, pero mientras quería ir haciendo el diseño, ¿es necesario para hacer el diseño tener ya en mano el dispositivo Apple?

Porque al intentar abrir el designer, me aparece eso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas conectarte a una Mac sí o sí para hacer las builds. Ejecuta como administrador el Visual Studio.

Comment: gracias @fredyfx, es una lata eso de iOS :(

Comment: de nada hermano, cambia el chip que tienes en tu C:\erebro, es fácil, sólo que necesitas encontrar la manera de cómo hacerlo así :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola bueno hace un tiempo ya se permite poder depurar y probar nuestro código sin necesidad de un Mac a través de la herramienta Live Player, eso si, si quieres compilar para exportación a la store necesitas de un Mac te dejo un enlace para más informacion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awgZDL1a3YI 
Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Muchas gracias @alesilvabk, ya revisé el vídeo